# Cognos 11.1.7 Framework manager change the table for the query subject, type data

Tags: sql, db2, cognos, db2-400

Using Cognos 11.1.7 and the database is DB2 on IBMi
DQM

Trying to figure out how to get Framework manager to change SQL definition on the fly, based on a value in the database

**This idea is based on a similar concept with parameter maps**.  You can change the SQL definition, however in the example below, it is based on a session parm.  This example is great for multi language as it changes the from statement of the SQL definition on the fly, like this:

```
  Select * from  [LIVE].TABLE_#$Parameter_map{key}#
```

It's also possible to do this by a parm passed when a report is run, but the user would not know what to pass.  So I tried something different...

**Why parameter map won't work**
This article explains a parameter map would not work because the value needs to come in before any queries are sent to any data sources
https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/unable-get-parameter-map-accept-query-item-its-input-parameter

**However, with SQL, I think it can**.  Here is what I have tried
A nested SQL statement where the sql inside the parenthesis if it resolved as a subselect would then complete the from statement by changing it to the correct table, like TABLE_A.

```
select * from (select X_VALUE from TABLE_X where X_CATEGORY = 'SALES')
```

For this example, TABLE_X has two columns -- X_CATEGORY   X_VALUE

X_CATEGORY   =  SALES

X_VALUE = TABLE_A

so select X_VALUE from TABLE_X where X_CATEGORY = 'SALES'

will return the value of 'TABLE_A'

btw, a never ending program toggles the value every 10 minutes TABLE_A or TABLE_B
as these tables are constantly being updated with pre-aggregated data

Unfortunately, in SQL (DB2 on IBMi), this returns X_VALUE instead of TABLE_A.
Maybe there is another way to accomplish this in SQL on DB2 for IBMi?  I am probably just running into a syntax issue

With SQL - How can you change the table in the from statement based on another table?

**Currently I have a work around**, using two sets of query subjects with the sql definitions hard coded.  Stitching them with a full outer join coalesce to common tables (like company, location, date, etc).

At the report level, I render the content based on TABLE_X

This works, however it is not user friendly and more difficult to maintain

Comment: Can you rewrite this to make it slightly clearer about what you want.  One problem is that rather a lot of what you wrote isn't in correct sentences.

Comment: Also, you want to have you query layer objects to be in the select * from table format and so you would want to do the modelling of this in the business layer model query subjects.

Comment: I rephrased/tried to make the request slightly clearer.  Showing my research, concepts that are similar to what I am trying to accomplish.  Examples.  Articles. and my current work around

Comment: `(select X_VALUE from TABLE_X where X_CATEGORY = 'SALES')` should return a "table" containing values in a column named `X_VALUE`.  So if only one row is returned, a value like `'TABLE_A'` is what you should expect to get.  What you won't get is a table reference like `TABLE_A`.  To be more clear about your question:  The database is designed to have valid data in only one table (TABLE_A or TABLE_B) at any given time and which table is valid can be found by running `select X_VALUE from TABLE_X where X_CATEGORY = 'SALES'` ?

Comment: Cognos isn't the problem here.  The overall design of expecting a reporting tool and/or your business users to know which table to use is the problem.  Having said that, maybe you could fake it by having a single view,and alter that view every 10 minutes to point to the other table?

Answer (score 0):

This is my understanding of the situation. One problem I'm having is that I've needed to guess a bit.

You have two data bases, each with the same structure of metadata.  You update the dbs continually.

You have a table which keeps the status of both DBs and there is {something} which you can use as the indicator of the most recently update DB.

It isn't clear how this is done or how many records are in this table.

You might want to try something along these lines. I have not tried it, so the details involve a considerable degree of hand-waving.

You can use parameter map macros in the data source connection properties in your FM model.

You would need to import the table which you are using to track the DB status.  You would create a filter in the query subject to find something like the maximum (if you are using time stamps) or filter for the value in the relevant column of the table which tells you which DB is current.  This would mean that only one row, representing the current db, would be returned.

You would create a parameter map which would pick up whatever value is returned for the relevant column in the query subject.  Put that macro into the appropriate property of the data source connection.

```
Key          Value
Sales        DB1's name
AnotherThing DB2's name
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use the QueryValue macro function to dynamically build up the FROM clause.  The example below will change the FROM claus to GOSALES. Camping Equipment.  (This will fail, given its not an actual table_name)  In your case you would replace
#dq(queryValue ('[Sales (query)].[Products].[Product line]'))#   with the database column which contains the table_name to be used.

```
SELECT
    "PRODUCT_LINE"."PRODUCT_LINE_CODE" AS "Product_line_code", 
   "PRODUCT_LINE"."PRODUCT_LINE_EN" AS "Product_line"
FROM
    "GOSALES".#dq(queryValue ('[Sales (query)].[Products].[Product line]'))# "PRODUCT_LINE"
```

Comment: You beat me to it.  `select * from #queryValue('[namespace].[TABLE_X].[X_VALUE]')#` based on http://cognospaul.com/2019/06/06/quickie-use-new-macro-function-queryvalue/  Once again the Cognos gurus find a way to subvert DBA nonsense.  If there are spaces in the table name, `select * from #dq(queryValue('[namespace].[TABLE_X].[X_VALUE]'))#`

Comment: One thing to note:  This is only available in version 11.0.[something] and forward and is only available if the model is configured to use DQM.  OP didn't provide that information about the target environment.

Comment: I stated at the top 11.1.7, and added DQM to clarify

Comment: I see.  I was probably looking at the tags.  Adding `cognos-11` may be helpful.