# User-Defined Function Nested in Macro - Framework Manager

Tags: oracle, macros, user-defined-functions, oracle12c, cognos

We are trying to create a dynamic query subject filter.  To do this, we are trying to nest an Oracle user-defined function inside of a macro.

Example query subject filter:

```
#strip(ORACLE_USER_DEFINED_FUNCTION())#
```

We have imported the oracle function ORACLE_USER_DEFINED_FUNCTION into Framework Manager.  The function returns a VARCHAR2 of the desired expression.  For testing purposes, this function is simply returning VARCHAR2 value of '`1=1`' (the single quotes are not part of the VARCHAR2 return value).

The idea being that we want the query subject filter expression to be dynamically generated at run-time so the resulting query contains `'...WHERE 1=1'`.  The `strip` macro is the mechanism to pre-process and invoke the user-defined function before the query is sent to the database.

However, when attempting to verify/check the query subject filter we receive the following error.

> XQE-GEN-0018 Query Service internal error has occurred, please see the log for details.

I'm trying to get a hold of the query service log, but don't yet have it.

Perhaps there is some casting needed to convert the oracle VARCHAR2 output from the function to an IBM/Cognos string that is acceptable input for the IBM/Cognos macro.

Your assistance is appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Using Oracle 12c and Cognos 11.1.

Comment: Dynamic Query Mode or Compatible Query Mode?

Comment: is the 1=1 to make the filter optional?

Answer (score 0):

With the exception of  the queryValue macro function, macros are evaluated prior to accessing the database.  This means the macro does not know what the Oracle UDF is or what its supposed to do.   If you are able to call the UDF via a FM query subject you maybe able to get away with something similar to the queryValue answer found here:

[Cognos 11.1.7 Framework manager change the table for the query subject, type data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67219557/cognos-11-1-7-framework-manager-change-the-table-for-the-query-subject-type-dat)